# php variable in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to call a url using php variables stored inside a mysql table column. For example:

In Mysql:

```
Table name:  geturldata
columns:    srno |  url
contents:   1 | http://www.google.com/number=$mobno&user=$username
```

Now, in php, i'll call this table like:

```
include (db.php)... 

$mobno = 91123456789;
$username = 'HELLOWORLD';

$QRY = "Select * from TBLNAME where srno=1";
$doqry = mysql_query($QRY);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($doqry);

echo $result_url = $res['url']
```

It shows:

```
 http://www.google.com/number=$mobno&user=$username
```

I want it to show:

```
http://www.google.com/number=91123456789&user='HELLOWORLD'
```

What should I change in MySQL table to get the above result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to substitute the variables in your URL (from MySQL) with the php variables set in your code.

Change the line:

```
ECHO $result_url = $res['url']
```

to something like this:

```
$result_url = $res['url'];
$result_url = str_replace("$username", urlencode($username), $result_url);
$result_url = str_replace("$mobno", urlencode($mobno), $result_url);
echo $result_url;
```

Comment: You could try 

    `$result_url = exec($res['url']);`

No idea if it'll work but could be worth a try. Failing that the solution above is the only realistic answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be single-quoted???  `str_replace('$username', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I would work with sprintf in this case:

Save it in db like:

```
http://www.google.com/number=%d&user=%s
```

And replace it later:

```
echo sprintf('http://www.google.com/number=%d&user=%s', $mobno, $username);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.